# Selenium WebDriver: Cannot find iframe within a form

Tags: html, selenium, iframe

I have an iframe that doesn't get found by webdriver in IE when I attempt to switchTo() it. There are two other iframes in the same context that do show up when I find all elements by the iframe tag. The only difference between those frames and this one is that it is inside a form,

```
<iframe 1></iframe>
<iframe 2></iframe>
<form>
    <iframe 3></iframe>
<form>
```

The above third iframe returns "no such iframe" when I attempt to switch to it. I know I am in the right context as I can switch into the other two iframes without issue.

**Edit: The form itself is not returning when I search for it by its ID. Is there a reason that a form wouldn't be visible to the webdriver?**

Comment: any difference in the way iframe are loaded ? Have you tried a wait command before looking for the 3rd frame ?

Comment: I have, the form itself doesn't want to return by id either, even after a wait for the whole page to load.


    <form arction method="POST" haschanged="0" ignorechanges"0" onsubmit="..." id="dummyid">

Comment: the behavior you are describing it is quite strange. Do you mind sharing the url you are working on for a better understanding of the issue ?